# VBA Code Efficiency Advice Needed

Tags: excel, coding-efficiency, vba

For very large Excel csv files (can be as large as 35MB+ & >100k rows), one of my processing steps is to check column A's "record type" indicator and depending on the value, cut/paste 2 sequential cells from different places in the row, over to the end of the row (columns 51 & 52).

The following code passed the 'CompileVBAProject' test, but I'm **certain** there are more efficient, much faster scripts that I'm just not thinking of. Yes, I'm a VBA semi-noob, but I'm trying to get better fast.  Got any advice?

```
    For i = 4 To rng.Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "10EE" Then
        Range("AW" & i & ":AY" & i).Copy Cells(i, 50)
        Range("AW" & i).ClearContents
        Else
            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "05EE" Then
                Range("M" & i & ":N" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                Range("M" & i & ":N" & i).ClearContents
                Else
                    If (Cells(i, 1).Value = "11EE" Or Cells(i, 1).Value = "25CP" Or Cells(i, 1).Value = "26EP" _
                        Or Cells(i, 1).Value = "51CL" Or Cells(i, 1).Value = "60PM") Then
                        Range("L" & i & ":M" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                        Range("L" & i & ":M" & i).ClearContents
                        Else
                            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "15EM" Then
                                Range("M" & i & ":N" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                Range("M" & i & ":N" & i).ClearContents
                                Else
                                    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "17EA" Then
                                        Range("X" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                        Range("X" & i & ":Y" & i).ClearContents
                                        Else
                                            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "20DP" Then
                                                Range("AC" & i & ":AD" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                                Range("AC" & i & ":AD" & i).ClearContents
                                                Else
                                                    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "24AH" Then
                                                        Range("AD" & i & ":AE" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                                        Range("AD" & i & ":AE" & i).ClearContents
                                                        Else
                                                            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "30EL" Then
                                                                Range("V" & i & ":W" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                                                Range("V" & i & ":W" & i).ClearContents
                                                                Else
                                                                    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "31EL" Then
                                                                        Range("O" & i & ":P" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                                                        Range("O" & i & ":P" & i).ClearContents
                                                                        Else
                                                                            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "40DE" Then
                                                                                Range("R" & i & ":S" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                                                                Range("R" & i & ":S" & i).ClearContents
                                                                                Else
                                                                                    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "50CL" Then
                                                                                        Range("AB" & i & ":AC" & i).Copy Cells(i, 51)
                                                                                        Range("AB" & i & ":AC" & i).ClearContents
                                                                                    End If
                                                                            End If
                                                                    End If
                                                            End If
                                                    End If
                                            End If
                                    End If
                            End If
                    End If
            End If
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: You should show how you set rng. I suspect .currentregion.

Comment: @Jeeped, after assigning variable lrow as count of the last row, here's the code:
    Set rng = Application.Range("A4:A" & lrow)

Comment: You could use a `Select Case Cells(i, 1).Value` rather than the `if -- else -- if else` cascade. It is unlikely to make the code much faster, but will make it more readable, which is an important first step towards making it more efficient.

Comment: @JohnColeman, thank you. I haven't used Select Case syntax before, but I'll get familiar asap. Agreed, the If-Then-Else cascade isn't very readable.

Comment: The highest tier of efficiency is always using arrays, so with such quantity of rows I would recommend reading on how to use arrays to process Excel ranges. For current code, as there are many changes to worksheet performed, `Application.ScreenUpdating  = False` before the loop and `Application.ScreenUpdating  = True` after will help.

Comment: @QFarley As an alternative to `Select Case` you could replace your current `Else If` lines with `ElseIf` lines (note the absence of a space after "Else"). This would prevent the need for so many `End If` statements at the end, and cut down on the deep indentation.

Comment: @JohnColeman I would stick to `Select Case`, because there will be no need to repeat `Cells(i, 1).Value` for each `Or`, each option will be comma delimited.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk I agree, but the way that OP is using `Else If` makes me suspect that they are not familiar with `ElseIf`, so I thought that it wouldn't hurt to point it out.

Comment: @JohnColeman I haven't used Else If before. Will read up on it.  Ryszard, Select Case looks a lot easier, and I'm using it for this instance. Also, I do have screenupdating lines, just much earlier in the code and at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Set rng = Application.Range("A4:A" & lrow)` then `For i = 4 To rng.Rows.Count` is incorrect.

A Select Case seems ideal for this. I combined "05EE" and "15EM".

```
with worksheets(1)
    For i = 4 To lrow
        Select Case .Cells(i, 1).Value2
            Case "10EE"
                .Cells(i, "AX").Resize(1, 3) = .Cells(i, "AW").Resize(1, 3).Value2
                .Cells(i, "AW").ClearContents
            Case "05EE", "15EM"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "M").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "M").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "11EE", "25CP", "26EP", "51CL", "60PM"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 3) = .Cells(i, "L").Resize(1, 3).Value2
                .Cells(i, "L").Resize(1, 3).ClearContents
            Case "17EA"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "X").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "X").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "20DP"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "AC").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "AC").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "24AH"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "AD").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "AD").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "30EL"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "V").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "V").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "31EL"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "O").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "O").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "40DE"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "R").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "R").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case "50CL"
                .Cells(i, "AY").Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, "AB").Resize(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(i, "AB").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    Next i
end with
```

If there are certain values that occur more frequently, they should be at the top of the Case conditions.

Comment: I tried plugging in your code, but I get the compile error "Invalid or unqualified reference" on the ".Cells" portion of the Select Case row.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you include the `with worksheets(1) ... end with` wrapper?

Comment: No, I had not seen it and hadn't copied.  Trying again.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to structure the data, and use arrays:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyVals()
    Const START_ROW = 4

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, map As Variant, arr As Variant, mapUb As Long

    Set ws = Sheet3         'Or: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange

    arr = rng               'Copy Range to Array
    map = GetMapping(map)   'Get Mapping: Values to Columns
    mapUb = UBound(map)

    Dim r As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    For r = START_ROW To rng.Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To mapUb
            If arr(r, 1) = map(i, 1) Then
                For j = 0 To map(i, 4)            'map4 = Offset col
                    '      map3 = copyTo col       map2 = copyFrom col
                    arr(r, map(i, 3) + j) = arr(r, map(i, 2) + j)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
    rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count + 1, 0) = arr
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetMapping(ByRef map As Variant) As Variant

 Const ITM = "10EE 05EE 11EE 25CP 26EP 51CL 60PM 15EM 17EA 20DP 24AH 30EL 31EL 40DE 50CL"
 Const SRC = "49 13 12 12 12 12 12 13 24 29 30 22 15 18 28"
 Const DST = "50 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51"
 Const OFF = "2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"    'Total columns to copy From / To + 1

    Dim v As Variant, s As Variant, d As Variant, o As Variant, i As Long

    v = Split(ITM)
    s = Split(SRC)
    d = Split(DST)
    o = Split(OFF)

    ReDim map(1 To UBound(v) + 1, 1 To 4) As Variant

    For i = 1 To UBound(v) + 1
        map(i, 1) = v(i - 1)    'Values
        map(i, 2) = s(i - 1)    'From First Col
        map(i, 3) = d(i - 1)    'To First Col
        map(i, 4) = o(i - 1)    'Total Cols (both From and To)
    Next

    GetMapping = map

End Function
```

---

.

```
Map Array returned by GetMapping()

                 Value       From First Col        To First Col         Total Cols (+ 1)

    map( 1, 1) = "10EE":    map( 1, 2) = 49:    map( 1, 3) = 50:    map( 1, 4) = 2
    map( 2, 1) = "05EE":    map( 2, 2) = 13:    map( 2, 3) = 51:    map( 2, 4) = 1
    map( 3, 1) = "11EE":    map( 3, 2) = 12:    map( 3, 3) = 51:    map( 3, 4) = 1
    map( 4, 1) = "25CP":    map( 4, 2) = 12:    map( 4, 3) = 51:    map( 4, 4) = 1
    map( 5, 1) = "26EP":    map( 5, 2) = 12:    map( 5, 3) = 51:    map( 5, 4) = 1
    map( 6, 1) = "51CL":    map( 6, 2) = 12:    map( 6, 3) = 51:    map( 6, 4) = 1
    map( 7, 1) = "60PM":    map( 7, 2) = 12:    map( 7, 3) = 51:    map( 7, 4) = 1
    map( 8, 1) = "15EM":    map( 8, 2) = 13:    map( 8, 3) = 51:    map( 8, 4) = 1
    map( 9, 1) = "17EA":    map( 9, 2) = 24:    map( 9, 3) = 51:    map( 9, 4) = 1
    map(10, 1) = "20DP":    map(10, 2) = 29:    map(10, 3) = 51:    map(10, 4) = 1
    map(11, 1) = "24AH":    map(11, 2) = 30:    map(11, 3) = 51:    map(11, 4) = 1
    map(12, 1) = "30EL":    map(12, 2) = 22:    map(12, 3) = 51:    map(12, 4) = 1
    map(13, 1) = "31EL":    map(13, 2) = 15:    map(13, 3) = 51:    map(13, 4) = 1
    map(14, 1) = "40DE":    map(14, 2) = 18:    map(14, 3) = 51:    map(14, 4) = 1
    map(15, 1) = "50CL":    map(15, 2) = 28:    map(15, 3) = 51:    map(15, 4) = 1
```

Comment: This is simply fantastic! I've not gotten to this level of sophistication in VBA coding, not by a long shot. What may be easy to an experienced coder is still foreign to a beginner, but I'm already reading up on this.  Thank you for my next area of VBA study!

Comment: I’m glad it helped. It’s worth reading up on arrays - took me a while, but once I figured them out, the concept became quite simple, and efficiency increases exponentially